# How do I get past the turrets at the beginning of test chamber 15, chapter 3

Tags: portal-2

The turrets whose sight you can block with the light bridge at the beginning, how do I get past them?

Pic:
[image: Beginning of chamber 15 with the one turret blocked]

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I actually came up with a different solution myself.  I stood by the portal and noticed that despite looking like the bridge is keeping you from using it, you still have half a usable portal.  So I walked through and picked up the turret and tossed it back through the portal.

[image]

Comment: Added a picture that I think describes what you're talking about

Answer (score 6):

Simply ignore the four turrets to the right; the bridge is in front of them so they're harmless.

As for the other one: with a portal, shoot a heavy light bridge in front of the single turret (like in the screenshot). Walk to the just-shooted bridge, and re-shoot the portal so the bridge disappears. If you're standing to the left or right of the turret, you can simply pick it up without it noticing you.

Answer (score 3):

I used a very low tech solution. First, I crouched down by the turrets on the right and grabbed one of the fallen ones. Using that, I knocked over the two that were still standing. I then walked over to the turret on the left and did the same thing. I've no idea if that was the intention, but it worked for me. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a fool-proof method, just grab the turret's leg below the light wall and toss it.  You might need to move the portal up a tiny bit so it's not hard on the floor, but it's impossible to get shot this way.

> Move up to the wall...
> [image]
>
> and grab it's leg.
>
> [image]

I prefer just being quick; shooting the portal that was sourcing the bridge (the blue portal) further on into the room and hustling through.

Answer (score 0):

Crouch in front of the light bridge.
grab the turret.
Wiggle the left stick or tap the WASD keys (depending on what system your using.)
Stop grabbing it.
Then it should fall over than shut off.
rinse and repeat for all turrets.